# What are some of the possible future applications of intelligent agents?

Tags: applications, chat-bots, intelligent-agent

I am trying to do some experiments with some intelligent agents, but I'm not sure how significant they will be in the future.

What are some possible interesting applications or use-cases of intelligent agents in the future?

For instance, it can be used as a virtual assistant instead of a real call agent. But what can be a more appealing application in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, what I can think of are the following applications, but there are potentially a lot more.

- **Decision Maker**: If you have any problem making a decision, intelligent agents can be used to weight evidence and give you statistics to rule out bad decisions.
- **Online Teacher**: In the far future, intelligent agents may acquire human-like skills, they maybe used to teach different students (from different backgrounds) at once, but the advantage here is that the intelligent agent can evaluate every student's level (skills, personality, intelligence, etc), and use this data to decide how to convey information to him (differently). It would be like a virtual world were children receive information in parallel, while taking different data about them into consideration: They can be used to better education.
- **Social Media**: I think intelligent agents will be integrated into social media, to analyze messages and comments, and warn users that some friends will dislike this or that or find it offensive, to give him time for making a decision about what to say. This would help limit bullying on social media.
- **Language Learning**: in the future (like in 10 - 20 years), intelligent agents will have the ability to generate human-level language, that would make it possible for them to generate infinite sentences and structures just like humans can do, and again they can evaluate user's level to generate listening and reading material. For a human, it would be just like talking to a native speaker of that language (or even better, since this "native speaker" would know everything about your level).